# Parsing server logs Python

Tags: python, database, pandas

I've been struggling to try and parse some server logs with Python and regex. I want to be able parse user agent strings in these lines and then eventually put them into a Pandas dataframe or a simple Excel spreadsheet.

So the following extract:

```
14/Aug/2018:00:44:50 +0000] 330 95.144.101.0, 34.255.205.1  GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 -   AlexaMediaPlayer/2.0.201528.0 (Linux;Android 5.1.1) ExoPlayerLib/1.5.9  client=VillaPlus&oid=2069&cid=22599&ad=54063&cr=August2018&target=25plus&action=ae&eventId=&cb=8874209&listenerId=f78d5ea146e92c4666efd2a389a8d2e8f6174bfc6777496e5e22735c426c&zone=679 -   pixelg.adswizz.com  https   533 TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,
15/Aug/2018:23:03:17 +0000] 330 79.77.250.195, 34.245.112.20    GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 -   Smooth/38 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X)  devicemap=mobile_tablet -   pixelg.adswizz.com  http    357 -   -   0.000,
15/Aug/2018:23:17:01 +0000] 330 77.100.181.37   GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 https://www.bonne-terre-data-layer.com/tag-manager.html?consumer=m.skybet.com   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15G77 SkyBet/6.8b474 (Sky Bet Mobile App)  client=SkyBet&event_id=Summer17&action=clientsitevisit&event=/my-bets   -   pixelg.adswizz.com  https   605 TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   0.000,
14/Aug/2018:01:00:55 +0000] 330 86.178.205.6, 34.244.204.228    GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 -   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36 client=MyHermes&oid=&cid=22731&ad=54477&cr=Hermes&target=selfemploy&action=ae&eventId=&cb=7699694&listenerId=0610d2ed750ab9f692daff922e1b2c04&zone=87   -   pixelg.adswizz.com  https   546 TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Becomes in a list:

```
AlexaMediaPlayer/2.0.201528.0 (Linux;Android 5.1.1) ExoPlayerLib/1.5.9,
Smooth/38 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X),
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15G77 SkyBet/6.8b474 (Sky Bet Mobile App),
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
```

Specifically I'm stuck on how to create the regex to pick up the user agent string in these different line formats. I would expect the code to look something like this:

```
import re
listofLines = ["[14/Aug/2018:00:44:50 +0000]    330 95.144.101.0, 34.255.205.1  GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 -   AlexaMediaPlayer/2.0.201528.0 (Linux;Android 5.1.1) ExoPlayerLib/1.5.9  client=VillaPlus&oid=2069&cid=22599&ad=54063&cr=August2018&target=25plus&action=ae&eventId=&cb=8874209&listenerId=f78d5ea146e92c4666efd2a389a8d2e8f6174bfc6777496e5e22735c426c&zone=679 -   pixelg.adswizz.com  https   533 TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
               "[15/Aug/2018:23:03:17 +0000]    330 79.77.250.195, 34.245.112.20    GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 -   Smooth/38 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X)  devicemap=mobile_tablet -   pixelg.adswizz.com  http    357 -   -   0.000",
               "[15/Aug/2018:23:17:01 +0000]    330 77.100.181.37   GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 https://www.bonne-terre-data-layer.com/tag-manager.html?consumer=m.skybet.com   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15G77 SkyBet/6.8b474 (Sky Bet Mobile App)  client=SkyBet&event_id=Summer17&action=clientsitevisit&event=/my-bets   -   pixelg.adswizz.com  https   605 TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   0.000",
               "[14/Aug/2018:01:00:55 +0000]    330 86.178.205.6, 34.244.204.228    GET pixelg.adswizz.com  /one.png    200 -   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36 client=MyHermes&oid=&cid=22731&ad=54477&cr=Hermes&target=selfemploy&action=ae&eventId=&cb=7699694&listenerId=0610d2ed750ab9f692daff922e1b2c04&zone=87   -   pixelg.adswizz.com  https   546 TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"]

regexuseragent = r"[200 |200    -   ]"


for line in listofLines:
    if re.findall(regexuseragent,line):
        print(regexuseragent)


    else: print("no useragent")
```

Comment: It looks like you can just open the log file in the spreadsheet and choose "TAB" as separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every string processing problem is a regular expression problem.

Your input lines appear to be tab separated. Split on tabs and take whichever index you want, e.g.

```
agent_string = line.split("\t")[8]
```